How to load 3D objects from an external local folder in unity?
I am doing a project in Unity3D and I need to upload 3D objects in fbx format dynamically. For this, I have a folder called "uploads" where I upload 3D files from an API. This uploads folder is outside the Unity project but at the same level (I'm testing it locally). How can I upload the 3D files hosted in the local Uploads folder inside my Unity project (locally anyway)?
I tried to download the 3D object from my absolute path using UnityWebRequest, but I cannot instantiate it inside Unity. However, I was able to download an image hosted in the same place and render it in my project, so I have access to that Uploads folder.

Could you post the code of what you tried please

You can't do it at runtime. FBX files get imported by the Editor using special C# classes that interface with C++ which are used by the importer and those are not available in the build. There is also no way, nor is it recommended to also include the Editor inside your final build. Furthermore, the game itself runs in a sandbox even within the Editor (being "locked" in the Assets folder) and while yes, there is some control over disk contents, normally you won't need them. As for WebGL builds, those are even more sandboxed. So for short: what you want can't be done.

Unity cannot (by default) load external models, materials etc. They have to be either part of the project, or delivered via an asset bundle (see Addressables).
If this is not an option for you, and runtime instantiation is a core requirement, then you will need to either build the functionality yourself (which would involve parsing the file, reconstructing the mesh data, loading textures and building materials etc). Alternatively, you can use an asset such as TriLib 2 which can do all of that for you.

I doubt TriLib can import and load models at runtime. Especially since on top of that you'd need to assign animations and much more than that. All those things, from rigging to scripting the anims, is done in the Editor. But I could be wrong ;)

It can - I've used it before! There are performance issues if your model is complex and you have large textures etc, but the basic principle works fine :)
I'm not sure it handles animations though, so you're probably correct there. Models, textures, materials are ok though.

Due to the difficulty of using fbx, I decided to use gltf objects inside the same server of my project and load them using the URL. To import them I used the glTFast project

Once the download is complete, save the Downloaded FBX file to a location inside your Unity project where you can access it. You can use "File.WriteAllBytes" to save the downloaded bytes to a file. After saving the FBX file locally within your Unity project, Unity will automatically detect and import it. You should see the FBX file appear in your project folder. Now that the FBX file is imported into Unity, you can instantiate it dynamically using Instantiate. You can create a prefab from the imported FBX file or directly instantiate the object.
You Can try this Example:
public string fbxDownloadURL = "http://localhost/uploads/myfile.fbx"; // Update with your actual download URL
public string localSavePath = "Assets/DownloadedFiles/myfile.fbx"; // Update with your desired local save path

IEnumerator Start()
{
    // Download the FBX file using UnityWebRequest
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(fbxDownloadURL);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        // Save the downloaded FBX file locally
        File.WriteAllBytes(localSavePath, www.downloadHandler.data);

        // Import the FBX file into Unity (Unity will automatically import it)
        yield return UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(localSavePath);

        // Instantiate the loaded 3D object
        GameObject loadedObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(localSavePath)));
        // Optionally, adjust position, rotation, and scale of the instantiated object
        loadedObject.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        loadedObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        loadedObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to download FBX: " + www.error);
    }
}


That can't work as in a WebGL build the Assets folder doesn't exist in that form anymore and assets are readonly

Further in a build you won't have access to UnityEditor at all - as the name suggests this entire assembly only exists within the Unity editor itself and is stripped of during the build
